# No logro filtrar un dropdown! Laravel 8 - AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel-8, filtro, dropdown

tengo esto:

```
public function create()
{
    $materia = new Materia();
    $programa = Programa::pluck('nombre_programas','id');
    $semestre = Semestre::pluck('numero_semestres','id');
    $grupo = Grupo::pluck('codigo_grupos','id');
    $listagrupo = Grupo::orderBy('id','ASC','codigo_grupos','ASC','cupo_grupos','ASC','estado_grupos','ASC','horarios_id','ASC')->get();
    $bancoMateria = Bancomateria::pluck('nombre_materias','id');
    $aula = Aula::pluck('nombre_aulas','id');
    $tipoaula = Tipoaula::pluck('nombre_tipoaulas','id');

    //filtroParaDocentesPorMedioDeFacultadeAlaQuePertenece
    $facultadData['data'] = Facultade::orderby("nombre_facultades","asc")->select("id","nombre_facultades")->get();

    $docente = Docente::pluck('nombre_docentes','id');

    return view('materia.create', compact('materia','programa','semestre','grupo','listagrupo','bancoMateria','aula','tipoaula','docente'))
        ->with("facultadData",$facultadData);

}

//ComplementofiltroParaDocentesPorMedioDeFacultadeAlaQuePertenece
public function getDocentes($facultadid=0)
{
    $docenteData['data'] = Docente::orderby("nombre_docentes","asc")->select("id","nombre_docentes")->where("faculdades_id",$facultadid)->get();

    return response()->json($docenteData);
}
```

Donde estoy usando la variable **$facultadData** en la función de **create** junto con la función **getDocentes**

les muestro las rutas

```
Route::get('/',[MateriaController::class,'create']);
Route::get('getDocentes/{id}',[MateriaController::class,'getDocentes']);
```

y así esta el código de la vista (*el script de ajax esta cargado en el en layout principal ya que este form es un include, ya probé poniéndolo acá pero es lo mismo*):

```
<div class="form-group">
        Facultad: <select name="sel_facul" id="sel_facul">
            <option value="0">-- Seleccione la facultad --</option>

            @foreach ($facultadData['data'] as $facultad)
            <option value="{{$facultad->id}}">{{$facultad->nombre_facultades}}</option>

            @endforeach
        </select>
        <br>
        Docentes: <select name="sel_doc" id="sel_doc">
            <option value="0">-- Seleccione el Docente --</option>
        </select>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#sel_facul').change(function(){
                    var id = $(this).val();

                    $('#sel_doc').find("option").not(":first").remove();
                    //CodigoAjax
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"getDocentes/"+id,
                        type:"get",
                        dataType:"json",
                        success:function(response){
                            var len = 0;
                            if (response['data'] != null) {
                                len = response['data'].length;
                            }
                            if (len>0) {
                                //lee los datos y crea la opcion
                                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                                    var id= response['data'][i].id;
                                    var name= response['data'][i].name;
                                    var option= "<option value='"+i+"'>"+name+"</option>";
                                    $("#sel_doc").append(option);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

pero lo que obtengo es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando elijo una facultad se supone que tienen que cargar los docentes relacionados con la categoría elegida pero no logro conseguirlo, nunca carga nada, por el contrario sale undefined agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda

adjunto un log::info que añadí cuando hago la seleccion de la facultad y quiero ver el docente:

```
[2022-03-17 23:30:00] local.INFO: array (
  'data' => 
  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::__set_state(array(
     'items' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      App\Models\Docente::__set_state(array(
         'perPage' => 20,
         'fillable' => 
        array (
          0 => 'nombre_docentes',
          1 => 'email_docentes',
          2 => 'faculdades_id',
        ),
         'connection' => 'mysql',
         'table' => 'docentes',
         'primaryKey' => 'id',
         'keyType' => 'int',
         'incrementing' => true,
         'with' => 
        array (
        ),
         'withCount' => 
        array (
        ),
         'preventsLazyLoading' => false,
         'exists' => true,
         'wasRecentlyCreated' => false,
         'escapeWhenCastingToString' => false,
         'attributes' => 
        array (
          'id' => 1,
          'nombre_docentes' => 'JHON DONE',
        ),
         'original' => 
        array (
          'id' => 1,
          'nombre_docentes' => 'JHON DONE',
        ),
         'changes' => 
        array (
        ),
         'casts' => 
        array (
        ),
         'classCastCache' => 
        array (
        ),
         'attributeCastCache' => 
        array (
        ),
         'dates' => 
        array (
        ),
         'dateFormat' => NULL,
         'appends' => 
        array (
        ),
         'dispatchesEvents' => 
        array (
        ),
         'observables' => 
        array (
        ),
         'relations' => 
        array (
        ),
         'touches' => 
        array (
        ),
         'timestamps' => true,
         'hidden' => 
        array (
        ),
         'visible' => 
        array (
        ),
         'guarded' => 
        array (
          0 => '*',
        ),
      )),
    ),
     'escapeWhenCastingToString' => false,
  )),
)
```

Comment: Ya sabes que las imágenes con código no son bien recibidas aquí. Necesitamos el código en modo texto para ayudarte mejor. En este caso te oriento hacia donde debes ir a buscar la solución pero no puedo darte una respuesta directa en estas condiciones, lo siento. Mírate https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/ .  Pulsa sobre [edit] para quitar las imágenes y poner el código en modo texto para más ayuda.

Comment: Lo siento error de principiante, ya mismo lo arreglo

Comment: Hola, de nuevo ya arreglé mi error de poner imágenes lo siento, espero me puedan guiar con la solución

Comment: Vale, perfecto, gracias por corregirlo. Pensé que tu error estaba relacionado con esto: `var id = $(this).val();` pero no, me equivocaba, eso funciona bien. Como no se laravel poco más puedo ayudarte, pero ahora la pregunta ya ha ganado puntos para ser respondida por quien lo sepa. Asegúrate que la parte de laravel devuelve datos. Suerte!

Comment: Vale, yo lo hice con un log y entiendo que si esta tomando la informacion correcta basandome en la base de datos pero no me lo muestra en la vista no entiendo porque

Comment: Sin tener ni idea de lo que realmente muestra ese log::info, me parece ver un nombre de campo denominado `nombre_docentes` y que quizas tu estas mirando de invocarlo así en el ajax: `var name= response['data'][i].name` ... Eso del `undefined` suena a error por una mala resolución de los datos pasados. ¿ese `response['data'][i].name` no será `response['data'][i].nombre_docentes`?  Lo dudo, pero verifica bien el json que te devuelve el laravel, si es que lo hace, con un `console.log(response['data'])` a ver si sale algo.

Comment: funcionó me cargó, guardé un registro, todo bien pero luego actualicé para confirmar que todo siguiera bien y dejó de funcionar hermano, ya la verdad no sé que hacer

Comment: SOLUCIONADO! gracias

Comment: Perfecto :-) Me alegro por ti. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Además del aporte de mi compañero masterguru, el cual tenia razón en esta parte del codigo:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
 var id = response['data'][i].id;
 var name = response['data'][i].nombre_docentes;
 var option = "<option value='" + id + "'>" + name + "</option>";
 $("#docentes_id").append(option);
}
```

Donde cambié name por nombre_docentes

Ahora el otro pequeño detalle estaba en este punto:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/getDocentes/' + id,
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {...
```

Acá la solución fue ponerle el / antes de getDocentes un error mio de vista realmente los dos lo fueron